# How to add fields to the Meteor.users collection

Tags: meteor

I want the Facebook accessToken that is stored in my user's document on the client. Following the [meteor documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_users), I should just add a new publish call.

**In server.js:**

```
Meteor.publish("access_token", function () {
  return Meteor.users().find(
    { _id : Meteor.userId() }, 
    {'services.facebook.accessToken': 1}
  );
});
```

**In client.js:**

```
Meteor.subscribe("access_token");
```

Alright, here's where I get lost. Should the accessToken just show up in the Meteor.users collection now for the logged in user? Like:

```
var user = Meteor.users.findOne({ _id : Meteor.userId() }); 
console.log(user); // includes services.facebook.accessToken now
```

Obviously, I've tried the above and the accessToken doesn't show up. Yes, I've confirmed that the mongo document contains services.facebook.

So... do I create a new client collection and somehow hook it up to the new publish? How do I get the accessToken?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you should use "fields" keyword

```
Meteor.users.find({ _id: this.userId },
    { fields: { the-extra-fields-that-you-want-go-here: 1 } }
);
```

http://docs.meteor.com/#fieldspecifiers

Comment: In fact you should remove the double parenthesis, this causes an error. The right answer if I'm not mistaken is : `Meteor.users().find({ _id: this.userId },
    { fields: { extra_fields: 1 } }
);`

Answer (score 4):

You can publish the field you want:

```
Meteor.publish( null, function() {
  Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {profile: 1, username: 1, ...}})
}
```

Comment: This is not always right. If you are exposing the users collection (users-online plugin), Meteor.users() will find all online users with users.find, for example.