# Trouble with privileges when adding custom field to a Meteor user

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm having trouble adding custom user fields to a Meteor user object (`Meteor.user`). I'd like a user to have a "status" field, and I'd rather not nest it under "profile" (ie, profile.status), which I do know is r/w by default. (I've already removed `autopublish`.)

I've been able to publish the field to the client just fine via

```
Meteor.publish("directory", function () {
  return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {username: 1, status: 1}});
});
```

...but I can't get set permissions that allow a logged-in user to update their own `status`.

If I do

```
Meteor.users.allow({
  update: function (userId) {     
    return true; 
}});
```

in `Models.js,` a user can edit all the fields for *every* user. That's not cool.

I've tried doing variants such as

```
Meteor.users.allow({
  update: function (userId) {     
    return userId === Meteor.userId(); 
}});
```

and

```
Meteor.users.allow({
  update: function (userId) {     
    return userId === this.userId(); 
}});
```

and they just get me Access Denied errors in the console.

The [documentation addresses](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_users) this somewhat, but doesn't go into enough detail. What silly mistake am I making?

(This is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019529/how-to-add-fields-to-the-meteor-users-collection) SO question, but that question only addresses how to publish fields, not how to update them.)

Answer (score 5):

This is how I got it to work.

In the server I publish the userData

```
Meteor.publish("userData", function () {
  return Meteor.users.find(
    {_id: this.userId},
    {fields: {'foo': 1, 'bar': 1}}
  );
});
```

and set the allow as follows

```
Meteor.users.allow({
  update: function (userId, user, fields, modifier) {
    // can only change your own documents
    if(user._id === userId)
    {
      Meteor.users.update({_id: userId}, modifier);
      return true;
    }
    else return false;
  }
});
```

in the client code, somewhere I update the user record, only if there is a user

```
if(Meteor.userId())
{
 Meteor.users.update({_id: Meteor.userId()},{$set:{foo: 'something', bar: 'other'}});
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
Meteor.users.allow({
  update: function (userId, user) {     
    return userId === user._id; 
  }
});
```

**From the documentation for collection.allow:**

update(userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier)

The user userId wants to update a document doc. (doc is the current version of the document from the database, without the proposed update.) Return true to permit the change.